# How to prove $\int_1^\infty e^{-t}\ln tdt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n[1-(t/n)]^n\ln tdt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Show that $\int_1^\infty e^{-t}\ln tdt=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n[1-(t/n)]^n\ln tdt$

If $n$ doesn't appear in the upper bound of the integration of the right side,then we can exchange the position of limitation and integration(because the right part converges),but I don't know how to deal with the current case.

This is the exercise 1.6(6) of Real Analysis and Probability by ROBER T B. ASH,so maybe some theorems like Dominated Convergence Theorem are needed.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/595635/42969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *key idea* is to use the Dominated Convergence theorem, with $$t\longmapsto f_{n}(t)=\begin{cases}\left(1-\frac{t}{n}\right)^{n},\quad t\in [0,n]\\0,\quad t\in \left]0,+\infty \right[\end{cases},\quad n\in \mathbb{N}$$
and $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_{n}(t).$$